# Display multiple point and connect them with line for each persion on google map API

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

Fairly new to the Google Maps Api. I've got an array of data that I want to cycle through and plot on a map. Seems fairly simple, but all the multi-marker tutorials I have found are quite complex.
Let's use the data array demo for an example:

```js
var demoData = {
    "persion": [
        {
            "firstName": "Ron Souza",
            "location": [
                {
                    "lat": "10.794",
                    "lng": "106.696"
                },
                {
                    "lat": "38.874",
                    "lng": "-89.670"
                },
                {
                    "lat": "35.461",
                    "lng": "-81.123"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Tablet Pro",
            "location": [
                {
                    "lat": "-3.426",
                    "lng": "-61.787"
                },
                {
                    "lat": "-9.796",
                    "lng": "-56.162"
                },
                {
                    "lat": "-28.150",
                    "lng": "-60.996"
                }
            ]
        }]
}
```

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXwN7.png)
I want to plot all of these points,when clicked to display we have an infoWindow pop up display firstName and the line to connect points as the picture.
Please help me

Comment: Please make a plunker or a fiddle and post it here, so others can play around that and help you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/thienvdt/bscpju55/
I want the inforWindow for both person 1 and person 2 is always appear and when we click on any person, system will appear a line to connect all point of this person.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`google.maps.Polyline`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple) object to create a new Polyline object and then attach it to the map

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
      {lat: 33.808678, lng:-117.918921},
      {lat: 33.818038, lng: -117.928492},
      {lat:33.803333, lng:  -117.915278},
      {lat:33.808038, lng: -117.928495}
    ];

    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: flightPlanCoordinates,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
```